# Changes made to source qualifier after mapping process informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I made a process as below

```
 source definition -> source qualifier -> filter Trans -> exp Trans -- 
                                                       |-------------|-----> target definition
```

the target definition is connected to both expression transformation and filter transformation. When I made changes to a column in source qualifier, I notice that the corresponding column in the filter transformation changes too, but not in the target definition.....

Am I right to conclude that a Target definition is not a transformation like filter or expression, hence it ignores the changes??

Comment: Target definition does not depend on the source definition or source qualifier, it's completely independent. Target definition depends on the storage object you will be saving your data to, such as a database table or a flat file, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Target definitions cannot be changed from the mapping designer. You have to edit it in "Target Designer". The non-reusable expression/filter transformations are part of the mapping and that is why it changed automatically.